# Delete by mistake authorized_keys vagrant cant connect anymore

Tags: ssh, vagrant, authorized-keys

I deleted in my vagrant the public key in authorized_keys.

Now i can't use vagrant ssh !

I tried to copy paste the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub in the authorized_keys. 
But it doesn't seem to work.

Where can i find the vagrant public ssh key to put in authorized_keys ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

did you use a custom box or a public one ?

For public one, you can retrieve the key from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub

If you have a custom box and still own the private key (on the host) you can run

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This will make a new public key and you can copy in authorized key

Comment: `ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` should make a new public key

Comment: No it was'nt the problem, my solution was to add my own private key in config.ssh (see documentation) and add my public key in authorized_keys file